# TextView in List is cut off Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i have problem that the toolbar is cutting the start on the list view .
i try to search online an answer but i couldn't find out .
please help me understand what i am doing wrong ...

content.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

custom_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:background="#dee2e2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.omermalka.noteapp.ListView">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_list_view" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please add link to screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the correct flags set to allow scrolling: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`

`<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>`

The following link provides a concise tutorial to help you get started https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout